# issue updating variable on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a condition for a the size of the browser window but my variable "windowsize" doesnt get updated and only the value on document load is the one considered. What am I doing wrong, do I need a global variable?

Here is what I have:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jcf.customForms.replaceAll();
    initCarousel();
    initCycleCarousel();
    initSlideShow();
    initOpenClose();
    initAccordion();
    jQuery('input, textarea').placeholder();

    .....
    ...

});

.....
...
// open-close init
function initOpenClose() {

var $window = $(window);
var windowsize = $window.width();

$(window).resize(function() {
  windowsize = $window.width(); 
});

  if (windowsize > 1200) {
    //if the window is greater than 1200px wide then..
        jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
            activeClass: 'active',
            opener: '> a',
            slider: '.drop-container',
            animSpeed: 200,
            event: 'over',
            effect: 'slideAlt'
        });
  }
  if (windowsize < 1200) {
    //if the window is greater than 1200px wide then..
        jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
            activeClass: 'active',
            opener: '> a',
            slider: '.drop-container',
            animSpeed: 400,
            event: 'click',
            effect: 'slideAlt'
        });
  }
});
```

}

Comment: try your code inside resize handler.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to run if I do that.

Comment: @user2300867 how or when your function call happen if u use this code `if (windowsize > 1200) {` outside resize

Comment: I have a responsive menu that works different when window less than 1200 but if user is to resize the window js should then give the right menu accordingly.

Comment: @user2300867 check with updated code,this will call onload and resize too

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
  jQuery(function(){
      updateContainer(); // Initial load call to check it did not require resize
  });
  $(window).resize(function () {
        updateContainer(); // If Resize happens call to check
   });

 function updateContainer() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize > 1200) {
        //if the window is greater than 1200px wide then..
        jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
            activeClass: 'active',
            opener: '> a',
            slider: '.drop-container',
            animSpeed: 200,
            event: 'over',
            effect: 'slideAlt'
        });
    }
  else
  {  
      jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
        activeClass: 'active',
        opener: '> a',
        slider: '.drop-container',
        animSpeed: 400,
        event: 'click',
        effect: 'slideAlt'
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: this wont work bc I need the code to also work when the browser window doesnt get resize and just on document load.

Comment: Well it does work but only until I resize the window and I need the code to also run if I never resize the window.

Comment: "$(document).ready" means run once document loads. Since "updateContainer" is included in docReady, it WILL run on both load AND resize.

Comment: im updating an app a more experienced developer built and it doesnt use $(document) ready but jQuery(function(){
 initOpenClose(); and then function initOpenClose() { my code...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Only one thing...The updated version works but it only works the first time I re-size. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: no no it call the function always when resize happens,put alert to check whther function calling or not nu

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
function initOpenClose() 
{
     var $window = $(window);
     var windowsize = $window.width();

     updateWindow();

     $(window).resize(function() {

          windowsize = $window.width(); 
          updateWindow();

     });

     function updateWindow()
     {
         if (windowsize > 1200) 
         {
                   //if the window is greater than 1200px wide then..
             jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
                activeClass: 'active',
                opener: '> a',
                slider: '.drop-container',
                animSpeed: 200,
                event: 'over',
                effect: 'slideAlt'
             });
        }
        else if (windowsize < 1200) 
        {
            //if the window is greater than 1200px wide then..
           jQuery('#nav > ul > li').openClose({
                activeClass: 'active',
                opener: '> a',
                slider: '.drop-container',
                animSpeed: 400,
                event: 'click',
                effect: 'slideAlt'
            });
         }
      }
}
```